# Fetch Program ApplicationExitCode for Unit Test

Tags: c#, nunit

I would like to check the ApplicationExitCode for my C# Console Program under test.  Below is my NUnit test method.  I am uncertain what to replace the question marks with.

My testing class method:

```
[Test]
public void ExitApplicationWithZeroOnNoErrors()
{
  string[] arguments = { "--version=43" };
  var program = new Program(arguments);
  Assert.AreEqual(Utility.Status.Success, ?????);
}
```

My main application Program.cs.

```
public class Program
{
    public int? Version { get; private set; }

    [STAThread]
    public static int Main(string[] arguments)
    {
        var program = new Program(arguments);
        return (int)Utility.Status.Success;
    }

    public Program(IEnumerable<string> arguments)
    {
        var parameters = new OptionSet()
                             {
                                 {"v|version=", "Client version number.", (int v) => Version = v},
                             };
        parameters.Parse(arguments);
    }
}
```

As an aside I am using NDesk.Options class for my parameter gathering.  I attempting to write Unit Tests and utilize TDD for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check the exit code as would be returned to the OS, you should check the value returned from `Main`. So you will have to run `Main`:

```
var returnValue = Program.Main(arguments);
Assert.AreEqual(Utility.Status.Success, returnValue);
```